# Angular 5 Subject<any> not getting latest update data from services after sibling component update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

My project structure:

```
1.Edit.component.ts
     share - folder
       2.one.component.ts
       3.two.component.ts
       Fileds - folder
         4.three.component.ts
```

I am using Subject at Service to update the data from inside of the share folder child and sibling components and serve the data to parent.

It's working perfectly for immediate share folder components. But not for three.component.ts. I don't know why it's not updating from three.components. But I am sure the data passed services correctly.

**Edit.components.ts**

```
constructor(
  private service: Service,
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private router: Router
) { this.updateDataFromForm(); }
updateDataFromForm() {
  this.service.formData.subscribe(data => {
    this.formData = data;
  });
}
```

**one.component.ts,two.component.ts,three.component.ts**

```
consturctor(private service: Service)
ngOnint() {
this.updateFormData()
}
updateFormData() {
this.formGroup['valueChanges']
.debounceTime(500)
.subscribe(data => { this.service.formUpdate(data)})
}
```

**Service.ts**

```
 formDataSource = new Subject<any>();
 formData = this.formDataSource.asObservable();

 formUpdate(data){
   this.formDataSource.next(data)
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure the service is the same in all the components? How are you providing it? Are they part of the same module?

Comment: share [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) of you'r code

Comment: @ChristianBenseler 
1) I am using the same services for all components. the edit.component is a common component. 
2) I am providing the data when FormGroup get an update on each component using services. 
3) Yes all of them in same module.

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working", does it mean the subscribe function is not called at all? or does it mean it's called but the `data` is undefined inside your subscribe function? you can check that by logging the data inside the subscribe function.

Comment: @BenediktSchmidt the subscribe function not call for three.components update.

Comment: in your code example the function is called `ngOnint()`, is this correct? because angular only triggers the init function if it is correctly defined as `ngOnInit`

Comment: yes, my working code having ngOnInit(). Not ngOnint()

Comment: have you checked if the `ngOnInit`is called?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171549/discussion-between-kevin-dhinesh-babu-and-benedikt-schmidt).